# Unity webgl screen gets cut off inside of browser

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

well i've done the space shooter tutorial and run the compiled webgl app in a html file, but I noticed that the top screen area is cut off I can scroll down and see the rest of the game app, the bottom shows as expected and if I press the fullscreen button, obviously the game shows off entirely on the screen but I want to show the entire screen in the browser not in the fullscreen mode, another thing I noticed is that if i zoom out the page to 75%, the screen in the browser shows as expected but if I zoom in to 100%, for example, that's when the top screen area gets cut off, I was thinking of giving a default zoom via js or css, but someone recommended not to depend on that, so what can i do??? please help...

[image]
with 100% zoom

[image]
with 75% zoom

here is the code for the html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unity WebGL Player | SpaceShooter</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="TemplateData/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
    <script src="TemplateData/UnityProgress.js"></script>  
    <script src="Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
      var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/Build.json", {onProgress: UnityProgress});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="webgl-content">
      <div id="gameContainer" style="width: 600px; height: 900px;"></div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="webgl-logo"></div>
        <div class="fullscreen" onclick="gameInstance.SetFullscreen(1)"></div>
        <div class="title">SpaceShooter</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the player resolution size specified in the Player (Edit -> Project -> Player) settings?

Comment: it has a resolution of 600px X 900px...

Comment: Hmm, your browser has 916 pixels to display it...seems like the html template is making things bigger for some reason. Can you put the (generated) html code somewhere I can look at it?

Comment: The post has been updated with the html code...

Comment: Huh. It should be 600x900. My guess is that the browser is doing something funky with its zoom levels...

Comment: Well I've found what the problem was, it appeared that i've a screen scale level of 125% instead of 100% and that is because I have difficulties on reading the size of the text, for me at 100% is to small so I increased the scale of the text to 125% on the control panel of windows, so everything got bigger as expected and even the browser got affected by this, but it showed the screen of the unity webgl cut off... so the solution is to revert back the screen scale to 100%...

Comment: That would do it.